# Reading regex string from Yaml file doubles backslashes

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to store regex patterns in a Yaml file like so:

```
---

Fidor:
  Fidor Rechnungsabschluss kurz:
    From: ^Rechnungsabschluss_(\d{2})_(\d{4})\.pdf
    To: \\2_\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor.pdf
  Fidor Rechnungsabschluss lang:
    From: ^Rechnungsabschluss_(\d{2})_(\d{4})_(\d+)\.pdf
    To: \\2_\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor_\\3.pdf
```

This is how I read them in Python:

```
In [18]: # %load test.py
    ...: import yaml
    ...:
    ...: open("rename-patterns.yaml", 'r')
    ...:
    ...: stream = open("rename-patterns.yaml", 'r')
    ...: patterns = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    ...: print(patterns)
    ...:
{'Fidor': {'Fidor Rechnungsabschluss kurz': {'From': '^Rechnungsabschluss_(\\d{2})_(\\d{4})\\.pdf', 'To': '\\\\2_\\\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor.pdf'}, 'Fidor Rechnungsabschluss lang': {'From': '^Rechnungsabschluss_(\\d{2})_(\\d{4})_(\\d+)\\.pdf', 'To': '\\\\2_\\\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor_\\\\3.pdf'}}}
```

So every `\` becomes `\\` upon reading them into a Python dict.

I tried to put the Yaml string into `'` or `"`, but nothing helped.

What am I missing?

### Edit

Even using `|` for literal strings (seen in [1]) did not help.

So this

```
---

Fidor:
  Fidor Rechnungsabschluss kurz:
    From: |
      ^Rechnungsabschluss_(\d{2})_(\d{4})\.pdf
    To: |
      \\2_\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor.pdf
  Fidor Rechnungsabschluss lang:
    From: ^Rechnungsabschluss_(\d{2})_(\d{4})_(\d+)\.pdf
    To: \\2_\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor_\\3.pdf
```

results in the same Python dict with `\` => `\\`:

```
{'Fidor': {'Fidor Rechnungsabschluss kurz':
           {'From': '^Rechnungsabschluss_(\\d{2})_(\\d{4})\\.pdf\n', 'To': '\\\\2_\\\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor.pdf\n'},
           'Fidor Rechnungsabschluss lang':
           {'From': '^Rechnungsabschluss_(\\d{2})_(\\d{4})_(\\d+)\\.pdf', 'To': '\\\\2_\\\\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor_\\\\3.pdf'}}}
```

[1] https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

### Edit 2: Ended up using `[0-9]+` instead of `\d+`

As I could not make it work, I neded up changing my yaml file to use `[0-9]+` for digits and prevent using backslashes.

```
---

Fidor:
  Rechnungsabschluss kurz:
    From: ^Rechnungsabschluss_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})[.]pdf
    To: \2_\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor.pdf 
  Rechnungsabschluss lang:
    From: ^Rechnungsabschluss_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]+)[.]pdf
    To: \2_\1_Rechnungsabschluss_Fidor_\3.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

'\' start a escape character sequence in string literals. In other words, in string literals , the character '\' and the following character(s) represent a single character. Read more about escape character sequence in [String literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

In your example, the '\\' is used to represent the character '\'.